# How can I make calculator using (native Win32 API)?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm beginner in Win32Api, I tried to make calculator but I failed because of conversion of data types between each other

**Example:**

```
int N1 = GetDlgItemText(WID,IDC_N1,NULL,NULL);
int N2 = GetDlgItemText(WID,IDC_N2,NULL,NULL);
int RESULT = N1+N2;
MessageBox(NULL,RESULT,L"Message",MB_OK);
```

The example in above tell me the following error
**(cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int' to 'LPCWSTR')**

And the reason for this error is conversion of data types between each other

Please anybody help me

Comment: You have to use MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_N1).  Lots more work needed, can't stuff a string into an int without wcstol().

Comment: @Hans Passant: MAKEINTRESOURCE function does not work good with my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is correct code for your task:

```
wchar_t Str1[100], Str2[100], ResStr[100];  
GetDlgItemText(WID, IDC_N1, Str1, 100);  
GetDlgItemText(WID, IDC_N2, Str2, 100);  
int N1 = _wtoi(Str1);
int N2 = _wtoi(Str2);
int RESULT = N1 + N2; 
_itow(RESULT, ResStr, 10);
MessageBox(NULL, ResStr, L"Message",MB_OK);
```

Useful links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645489(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Michael- this work fine with integer numbers but with float numbers no

Comment: For floats you can use _wtof and _gcvt functions, and declare N1, N2 and RESULT as "double" of course.

Comment: but _gcvt funcion for ANSI not for wide-character

Comment: You are correct. swprintf(Str1, L"%f", YourFloatVariable) will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass unicode string instead of int to MessageBox.

```
wchar_t ResStr[100]; //define string  
_itow(RESULT, ResStr, 10); //convert int result to string  
MessageBox(NULL, ResStr, L"Message",MB_OK); //now display string
```

Comment: That's the second problem of your code. GetDlgItemText returns text as string, not as integer. This page has an example of using this function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644996(v=vs.85).aspx#modal_box

Answer (score 1):

There is an API for this. Use `GetDlgItemInt`.

Answer (score 0):

Your project isn't set to use Unicode, but you're passing a wide string to `MessageBox`. You can:

1) Change your project settings so that it defaults to Unicode; or

2) Explicitly call `MessageBoxW`; or

3) Remove the `L`, and use the non-Unicode API.

Comment: chys-- I have already been used the following code: #ifdef UNICODE
#define MessageBox  MessageBoxW
#else
#define MessageBox  MessageBoxA
#endif // !UNICODE  ----------- The problem is still

Comment: The problem isn't due to unicode/ansi, the problem is due to MessageBox requires a null-terminated string as the second parameter, not integer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to go to project>properties>configuration properties>and change 'character set' to Multi-Byte. It will probably be at Unicode, I think this will work because that's the error I always get when I try to use the WinAPI MessageBox() before changing the character set. Maybe you're trying to do something different? But this should help...